# Weird symbol stored in a NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I get a weird text symbol when I output the content of a `NSString`. A user sent its database and it is stored in core data. This is what the symbol looks like:

[image]

I guess it does have some specific code, or is it a not supported character? The user can't explain from where such symbol comes from.

Thanks

Comment: Could it be an Emoji?

Comment: @rckoenes How can I debug this. Is there a way to print the encoding, or any tip how could I investigate it?

Comment: `NSLog(@"The char code is %d", (int) [theString characterAtIndex:4]);`

Comment: Or show the output of `NSLog(@"%@", [theString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding])`.

Comment: And the answer is U+61480 . I checked on this website and it is just a square: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=398464 Not sure how to fill this

Comment: @HotLicks I'm parsing characters from a html string (which I don't have with me, because the user doesn't know anymore) so maybe it is just an unsupported character on osx?

Comment: Either you've garbled it or it is garbled from prior improper conversions.  That's 0xF028 -- 0x28 is left paren, not particularly helpful.  If there was an endian switch it could be 0x28F0 or 10480, but that's an obscure "OSMANYA LETTER ALEF" -- unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at NSString's class description. You can use the 'canBeConvertedToEncoding' iteratively, with all possible encodings listed in the 'String Encodings' section at the bottom, to find out which one your strings use.